# Selenium grid: Where browser windows should be opened - on the box with hub or on the box with remote controls?

Tags: selenium

I'm running a hub on remote machine and connect several remote controls from my local box to the hub. The question is - where the browsers should be opened after the test - on the box with hub or on my local box?

Currently the browsers are opened on my local box and I'm a little bit confused because I was sure that the browsers should be opened on the remote machine where the hub is deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser should open in remote machines. You should keep remote controls in multiple remote machines so that the test gets distributed. You are doing the exact opposite it seems. Check this link to see more details : http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/how_it_works.html